# Wobbly rendering when resetting value of v-radio component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-reactivity

I am using `v-radio` components with a custom label like this:

```
<v-radio-group
  v-model="myData.selectedItem"
  :rules="[value => !!value]"
  class="radio-card-grid"
>
  <v-radio
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item.id"
    :value="item.id"
    on-icon=""
    off-icon=""
    class="radio-card"
  >
    <template #label>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text class="pa-0">
          <v-icon class="mt-2">
            {{ item.icon }}
          </v-icon>
          <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </template>
  </v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

The classes `radio-card-grid` and `radio-card` style the `v-radio` components in a grid of square buttons.

The whole thing is inside of a `v-bottom-sheet` that I use as a modal dialog.

The initial value of `myData.selectedItem` is `undefined`, so no `v-radio` is selected. When a `v-radio` is clicked, the value is being set according to `item.id` (which is unique in the set of items).

After closing the dialog, another dialog is being opened. This second dialog allows to navigate back to the first dialog.

**Here's the issue:**

When I open the dialog for the first time, everything works as expected. I select an item by clicking one of the `v-radio`, then the second dialog opens.

If I then go back to the first dialog, I reset the value of `myData.selectedItem` back to `undefined` in order to have a fresh dialog with no `v-radio` selected. This causes the whole layout to wobble a couple of times. Wobbling means that the `v-cards` slightly change their size and/or position (I can't really say what exactly is going on there), which causes the whole grid to wobble. The performance tab in the Chrome dev console shows lots of render events and Layout Shifts ([interesting video on what that means here](https://web.dev/optimize-vitals-lighthouse/)) while the wobbling occurs.

If I set the value of `myData.seletedItem` to one of the item id's instead, no wobbling occurs.

So this issue seems to be related to how the `v-radio` components are being checked if they are the one that is being selected - or something like this.

This is how far I could nail down the issue but I couldn't figure out hot to mitigate the issue or how to prevent it in the first place.

A workaround could be to add a hidden `v-radio` that is being selected to give the impression that no `v-radio` is being selected, but I would prefer to understand the issue and fix it without workarounds.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: I was able to further nail the issue down by removing the line `:rules="[value => !!value]"` from the `v-radio-group` component. So apparently this happens when the validity of the input is being checked.

Comment: Any chance you could repro this in codesandbox.io? Try to add just enough to repro, but not more. There's a high chance you'll find the answer yourself while trimming it down but, if you don't, I'll have a go at it once I have eyes on it.

Comment: Hey @tao, thanks for the offer! I found what needs to be trimmed while writing this question (see my edit). But I still don't understand why using the `:rules` parameter is causing this. Might be something only the Vuetify core team can explain :-P

Comment: Since their code is open source, that's technically not true. Besides, you wouldn't have asked here if you truly believed that. Right?

Comment: One suspicion I have is the error message that would be displayed if I would use the `:rules` parameter. This adds a class `error--text` to the  `v-radio-group` and maybe some CSS is wrong here. But why is it updating so many times that it causes wobbling? And what do I need to overwrite to get rid of it (best case: get rid of the whole `error--text` class).

Comment: In my experience, this type of bugs are solved by stepping through the entire update cycle one step at a time. You only need two tools: `console` + `debugger`. Everything in the browser can be slowed down, traced, or stopped.

Comment: I actually posted here because Vuetify doesn't have its own forums and directs to SO for discussion :-P If it was for Vue, it would usually be someone from the core team who explains such odd behavior in their own forums... Technically I could read that code, but practically it would most probably not help me to understand the WHY.